# React Native FlatList Rerender from Descendant

Tags: react-native

Sorry, folks, I did attempt to do my research on previous questions.

I have the following Component implemented as a screen in my application:

```
class DivisionManagmementScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            divisions: [],
            toggle: true
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {

        let programId = this.props.navigation.getParam("programId", 1);

        this.db = await open({name: "stats.db",createFromLocation: "~soccerstats.db"});

        const sql = "SELECT * FROM DIVISION where DIVISION_PROGRAM_ID = ? ORDER BY DIVISION_NAME";

        let result = await query(this.db, sql, [programId]); 

        this.setState({divisions: result.result});
    }

    async componentWillUnmount() {
        await close(this.db);
    }

    _renderItem = ({item}) => (
        <DivisionManagementRow divisionId={item.DIVISION_ID} divisionName={item.DIVISION_NAME} />
    );


    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.component}>
                <View style={styles.listArea}>
                    <FlatList 
                        data={this.state.divisions}
                        renderItem={this._renderItem}
                        keyExtractor={(item) => item.DIVISION_ID.toString() }
                        extraData={this.state.toggle}/>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.bottomButtonArea}>
                    <View style={styles.bottomButtonSection}>
                        <MenuNavigationButton label="Add Division" target="AddDivisionScreen" />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default withNavigation(DivisionManagmementScreen);
```

Note that I am using the passing `this.state.toggle` as the parameter for my FlatList `extraData` parameter.

Below is the implementation of the Row of data that FlatList renders (minus styles, proptypes, etc):

class DivisionManagementRow extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {toggle: true};

}

_btnTeams = () => {

    // navigate to Team Management
}

_btnEditDivision = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("EditDivisionScreen", {divisionId: this.props.divisionId});
}

_btnDeleteDivision = () => {

    console.log("Entered _btnDeleteDevision");
    Alert.alert(
        "Are you sure?",
        "This will delete all teams that are assigned to this division. Are you sure you want to do this?",
        [
            {text: "Cancel"},
            {text: "Ok", onPress: () => this._deleteDivision()}
        ]
    );
}

_deleteDivision = async () => {

    console.log("Entered _deleteDivision, divisionId: " + this.props.divisionId);
    const sql = "DELETE FROM DIVISION WHERE DIVISION_ID = ?";

    let divisionId = this.props.divisionId;
    let db = await open({name: "stats.db",createFromLocation: "~soccerstats.db"});
    let result = await execute(db, sql, [divisionId]);

    console.log("Rows affected: " + result.rowsAffected);

    await close(db);

    this.setState({toggle: !this.state.toggle});

}

render() {

    return (
        <View style={styles.component}>
            <Text>{this.props.divisionName}</Text>
            <View style={styles.buttonSection}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
                onPress={this._btnAddTeam}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Teams</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
                onPress={this._btnEditDivision}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Edit</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
                onPress={this._btnDeleteDivision}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Delete</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

The first two "buttons" (TouchableOpacitys) work fine, as they simply navigate to different screens. However, the third, "Delete", doesn't have a screen; it shows an alert to confirm the operation, then runs the delete code in the _deleteDivision() method. Unfortunately, the execution of that method does not force a rerender of the FlatList.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Since you delete a record from your data array that you query, you need to refech/query the items and update the state so that your `FlatList` shows the new items. To achieve this you can do the steps below;

1. Move your query functions out of the `componentDidMount` life-cycle method to a separate function then call that function in `componentDidMount`
2. Pass down a property to your `DivisionManagementRow`. Assign a function to this property.
3. Rerun the query function in this function you passed down.
4. Run this function after you successfully deleted your item.

**Sample** *(removed some parts for simplicity)*

```
class DivisionManagmementScreen extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.db = await open({name: "stats.db",createFromLocation: "~soccerstats.db"});
    this.fetchItems()
  }
  async componentWillUnmount() {
    await close(this.db);
  }
  fetchItems = () => {
    let programId = this.props.navigation.getParam("programId", 1);
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM DIVISION where DIVISION_PROGRAM_ID = ? ORDER BY DIVISION_NAME";
    let result = await query(this.db, sql, [programId]); 
    this.setState({divisions: result.result});
  }
  _renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <DivisionManagementRow 
      divisionId={item.DIVISION_ID} 
      divisionName={item.DIVISION_NAME}
      onDelete={this.fetchItems}
    />
  )
  render() {
    return(
      <View style={styles.component}>
        <View style={styles.listArea}>
          <FlatList 
              data={this.state.divisions}
              renderItem={this._renderItem}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.DIVISION_ID.toString() }
              extraData={this.state.toggle}/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.bottomButtonArea}>
          <View style={styles.bottomButtonSection}>
              <MenuNavigationButton label="Add Division" target="AddDivisionScreen" />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

---

```
_deleteDivision = async () => {
  const sql = "DELETE FROM DIVISION WHERE DIVISION_ID = ?";
  let divisionId = this.props.divisionId;
  let db = await open({name: "stats.db",createFromLocation: "~soccerstats.db"});
  let result = await execute(db, sql, [divisionId]);
  await close(db);
  this.setState({toggle: !this.state.toggle}, () => {
    this.props.onDelete(); // running passed down function
                           // after state set   
  });
}
```

Comment: bennygenel: thanks for your response. I ultimately ended up refactoring both classes, and making DivisionManagementRow a "dumb" component that received callbacks from DivisionManagement, with all database code defined in that class.

Comment: @Jason No problem. Glad if I did help. If you application has similar functionalities across, you should consider moving all database related logic into it's own class(not a react component class) and call them accordingly from your component. Also you can consider using redux too.

Comment: The database logic is in its own separate file called DbUtils.js. I considered learning redux for this project, but it currently seems like overkill.

The DbUtils class is at https://github.com/fergusonjason/commons/blob/master/react-native/sqlite/DbUtils.js in case it would help anyone else.